# Circle Ci loop on cdk destroy

Tags: aws-cdk, circleci

I want to run a job to destroy my stack after it is created.

The commands i tried:

```
cdk destroy
sudo cdk destroy
cdk destroy <stack name>
npx cdk destroy
```

The `cdk deploy` command does the job.
The cdk destroy command does the job on my dev machine.

If I run `cdk list` I get the stack name that i want to delete.

If I ssh in the build I can run `cdk destroy` and the comand executes.

Anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been solved using `npm scripts` as the deployment concerns typescript cdk.

```
scripts: {
  "cdk_deploy": "cdk deploy",
  "cdk_destroy": "yes | cdk destroy"
}

- run:
name: deploy
command: npm run cdk_deploy
- run:
name: destroy
command: npm run cdk_destroy
```